# Check if ArrayCollection is empty

Tags: symfony, arraycollection, symfony-2.2

I have an Entity Order which hold Suppliers in an Arraycollection.
In my controller i want to check if this arraycollection is empty:

```
$suppliers = $order->getSuppliers();
```

I tried:

```
if(!($suppliers)) {}
if(empty($suppliers)) {}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Doctrine ArrayCollection has a method `isEmpty` that will do what you are looking for.

```
if ($suppliers->isEmpty()) { }
```

Take a look at the documentation for it [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/latest/index.html#isempty)

Comment: Note: This is preferable over count() == 0. http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#343-353

Comment: Yes, and you are bond to Doctrine (for ever) :-/

Comment: @UrosMajeric - not really, you would just need to ensure that your concrete methods (or your own interface) matched the Collection interface if you migrated away from Doctrine.

Comment: In addition to what @KenHannel said, one could also add `Order::hasSuppliers(): bool` method, which returns `$this->suppliers->isEmpty()`. This way, if someday you decide to migrate from Doctrine, you will need to change your code in only one place.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the `count()` PHP function:

```
if (count($suppliers) < 1) { }
```